# Can I simply take my angular app (those scripts in dist folder) and import it to a React application and make it run inside that React App?

Tags: reactjs, angular, typescript

as you can see from the title I am trying to put my **Angular app into a React app**. However I successfully did this by help of WebComponents that I exported my Angular App as a WebComponent and imported to React app and It worked well. But one of my colleagues thought that we can simply **make use of those scripts reside in dist folder of Angular project**. He suggested trying to use them in the React App. Then I got those errors on the console and Angular App did not work. I dont think it is not much easy but anyway I need your helps and comments :) Do you think I can easily make my angular app run in react by just importing those files( **runtime,pollyfills,main js files** )?
**this is the app.tsx file**

```
import { AppHeader } from '@corva/ui/components';
import { DEFAULT_SETTINGS } from './constants';
import logo from './assets/logo.svg';

import './runtime.00c54c7e2dcbef2e.js';
import './polyfills.55bb5cf061565b63.js';
import './main.820dbef75dbda196.js';
import styles from './App.css';
import React from 'react';
type AppProps = {
  isExampleCheckboxChecked?: boolean;
  appHeaderProps: {
    [key: string]: any;
    app: any;
  };
};
function App({
  isExampleCheckboxChecked = DEFAULT_SETTINGS.isExampleCheckboxChecked,
  appHeaderProps,
}: AppProps): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <AppHeader {...appHeaderProps} />
      <div className={styles.content}>
        <div>
          <img src={logo} alt="logo" className={styles.logo} />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
            <br />
            <br />
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          Settings &quot;Example&quot; checkbox is{' '}
          {isExampleCheckboxChecked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
        </div>
        <app-root></app-root>

      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
// Important: Do not change root component default export (App.js). Use it as container
//  for your App. It's required to make build and zip scripts work as expected;
export default App;
```

[image: and here is the console with errors:]

Comment: Most likely you are not going to be able to just use the dist files that were built for an Angular application. If WebComponents works, why not go that route? I imagine the alternative would be to translate all the Angular code to React, which is probably not ideal.

Comment: Hello @segFault thanks for reply. And the reason behind this wish was actually that discussion regardig memory issues and deconstracting the webcomponent. https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/754 . I am not an expert on webcomponents so maybe you could make some comment on this.